# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to download a Excel on my local computer from my web application deployed on Google App Engine. The Entity from I get the data, have not Text fields.

All the fields are String. However, when I reach the line `(String) catalogo.getProperty("des_definidor")` in a object which `des_definidor` field is 538 characters length (and 538 bytes, I calculated), I get this error. I thought the characters limit for a String was 1500 bytes in an Entity field.

Someone knows what is the problem? Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

to convert com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text to a String use getValue method on Text:

```
String value = someText.getValue();
```

Ordinary Java strings indeed stored as properties in Entity objects are limited to 1500 bytes.

for more info, check [Java documentation for App Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text).